# Android java HCE card emulation as defult

Tags: java, android, nfc, hce

I use Cordova plugin to emulate card https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hce/tree/master.

For start I try to get event from reader:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

  hce.registerCommandCallback(onCommand);
}

            
    function onCommand(command) {

    console.log ("command: " + command);
    
    }
```

I run application and tap my phone to reader, it's call wallet with my card and in console no any command...

Please help, how to set "priority" for my app? Thanks!